# New Product Attribute screen coming blank in magento 1.9

Tags: magento, attributes, product

In magento 1.9
When I go to Catalog --> Attributes --> Manage Attributes

and click on add new attribute

then screen is coming blank...

When i edit an attribute then also screen is coming blank

which you can see in image[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kTp2.png)

Please resolve this issue...

Comment: Have you make any change to core module?
If not , check This with disable your installed extensions one by one.

You can also find issue by enable the developer mode Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true); in index.php

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

To see the exact error, you need to Uncomment script in `index.php`. Like Below:

Find this line "`#ini_set('display_errors', 1);`" and remove #sign. After that refresh the edit attribute page.